# Can't start roscore, because rosout is not built

Tags: raspberry-pi, ros

I am trying to start ROS Master on my Raspberry Pi3 (ROS Indigo) but it shows me an error instead:

```
"ERROR: rosout is not built. Please run 'rosmake rosout'

failed to start core service [/rosout]
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file"
```

After running `rosmake rosout`, I get this message:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rosout']                                  
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/pi/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20171117-153157
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rosout'] to:
[]                                     
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['rosout']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

I followed installation instructions from [wiki.ros.org](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi). I've searched for this error but haven't found anything that applies. Does anyone has a clue what might be a reason?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?